# Octopus deploy ID vs Name vs slug for scripting

Tags: naming, octopus-deploy

I'm writing powershell scripts to query data from Octopus, sooner or later I need to have a reference to a project or environment in the script. Is it better to use the Name, Id or slug in these situations? Readability and maintainability / brittleness of the scripts are concerns.

- **ID** seems unambiguous, but is hard to read in the script as it has no semantic meaning (eg "**Projects-197**")
- **Name** is very human readable, but seems likely to change for style reasons (eg "**Public web app**")
- **slug** seems to be just a url-safe version of the name ("eg "**public-web-app**")

Many relative ID's can be looked up from other queries (the release-ID for a given deployment for example) but eventually we need to refer to one specific project.

Comment: What GitHub mean by "slug"?..

Comment: @YvesM. It's a feature of Octopus Deploy, not github. Objects have an identifier called a "slug" - which (unless it's changed in the past 6 years) is a url safe, but human readable string based on the name of that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would recommend using the ID as the name is not necessarily unique (variable names, for example) and the ID can't be changed.

When you say "is hard to read in the script as it has no semantic meaning" does that imply you are hard-coding the name/id into the script? Why not put a comment? For example,

```
$project-id = "Projects-123" # ID of "My Awesome Project"
```

Comment: Looking back on this I think you're right. Combined with descriptive variable naming, and ensuring the project-ID is only defined once. Something like: `$my-awesome-project-id = "Projects-123" # ID of "My Awesome Project"`